# Prove that a normal matrix can be completely determined by its eigen values and a unitary matrix.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, unitary-matrices

Prove that a normal matrix can be completely determined by its eigenvalues and a unitary matrix. 
I tried using the Spectral decomposition theorem: Is states that a normal matrix N with spectrum set {$k_1, k_2,.., k_n$} can be represented as N = $k_1P_1 + k_2P_2 + ... + k_nP_n$
where for i,j belonging to [n] and $P_iP_j$ = P_i if i = j, else 0.

I tried making it all a matrix with multiplication of a diagonal matrix containing all the eigen values and another matrix containing all the $P_is$, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea. A consequence of the spectral decomposition theorem is the that any normal matrix is unitarily diagonalizable:
$$A=U^{-1}DU$$
Where $U$ is unitary and $D$ is diagonal. This means that given the corresponding unitary diagonalizing matrix and the eigenvalues of $A$ (which give you its diagonal form), you can find $A$ using this exact formula.

Comment: There's one problem with this: if you're given the **set** of eigenvalues (or rather **multiset**, since there can be repetitions), you don't know in which order they should appear on the diagonal.  So for $U = I$ and eigenvalues $\{1,2\}$, the matrix could be either $\pmatrix{1&0\cr 0 & 2\cr}$ or $\pmatrix{2 &0\cr 0 & 1\cr}$.

Comment: I agree. But you can agree that the eigenvalues are presented in increasing order (since you 'choose' the protocol of how the normal operator is represented).